# UK - Closed Company, Bank has frozen the remaining funds

Tags: united-kingdom, bank-account, limited-liability-company, business

I recently closed my small business and left a few hundred £s in the business account with Barclays. After receiving notification that the company has been officially struck off, I contacted Barclays to go about getting the remaining funds out. They inform me that they "followed protocol" and now the account has been frozen and my next move should be to contact a solicitor.

Is there anything can I do about this? It seems mad that they can freeze the account yet offer no solution or even advice to go about getting the funds back. I don't see how a solicitor has any more authority than I do over the bank account. I actually don't even have a solicitor and predict that the process of hiring one will outweigh the funds I'd recover.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not personally familiar with this, but I had a look at [the Companies House guidance](http://www.companieshouse.gov.uk/infoAndGuide/windingUpCompany.shtml).

Unfortunately, it seems you've done things in the wrong order. You should have first got the funds out, distributed them to yourself as a dividend or salary, and then closed the account, and then wound up the company. Legally speaking, the remaining funds now belong to the government ("bona vacantia").

It's possible you could apply to have the company restored, but I think that might be difficult; I don't think the administrative restoration procedure applies in your situation.

Given the amount involved, I'd suggest just forgetting about it.

Comment: "Given the amount involved, I'd suggest just forgetting about it." I was afraid of that :( I'm going to give Barclays another call to see if I can get anywhere.

Comment: To follow this up, everything was going ahead for claiming it back, until I needed a commissioner for oaths or solicitor to sign the form, thus making it not worthwhile after fees.